# How to read multiple json files stored in a folder into different dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Suppose there are 20 JSON files in a folder and I want to read & store them into 20 different dictionaries in a python program.

Comment: You really mean a list of dictionaries, don't you?   Or a dictionary of dictionaries?  Are your keys based on filenames?

Comment: A list of dictionaries will do or nested dictionaries. No keys aren't based on filenames. All .json files/dicts have the same keys but different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `list` to hold the filenames, then apply the dict reading for each

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']  # ...
dicts = [json.loads(Path(file).read_text()) for file in files]
```

Comment: I believe the read could be simplified as `json.load(Path(file))`

Comment: @RufusVS nope. `dicts = [json.load(open(file)) for file in files]` works but doesn't close files, Path().readtext does

Comment: Each file is closed as soon as the load function returns.

Comment: @RufusVS autoclosing is only happening if you use the contexthandler `with open(filename) as f: ....` - if you just use `f = open(filename)) you need to do `f.close()` as well

Comment: This is not `f=open(filename`.  This is `somefunc(open(filename))`.  when `somefunc` returns, the file reference will be closed.